# How to setup custom DNS with Azure Websites Preview?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I created a new Azure Website, using Umbraco as the CMS.  I got a page up and going, and I already have a .co.nz domain with www.domains4less.com.  There's a whole lot of stuff on the internet about pointing URLs to Azure, but that seems to be more of a redirection service than anything (i.e. my URLs still use azurewebsites.net once I land on my site).

Has anybody had any luck getting it to go?

Here's the error I get when I try adding the DNS entry to Azure (I'm in reserved mode, reemdairy is the name of the website):

> There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few
>   moments.
>
> Browser: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5 User language: undefined
>   Portal Version: 6.0.6002.18488 (rd_auxportal_stable.120609-0259)
>   Subscriptions: 3aabe358-d178-4790-a97b-ffba902b2851 User email
>   address: touchmaniacs@live.com
>
> Last 10 Requests
>
> message: Failure: Ajax call to: Websites/UpdateConfig. failed with
>   status: error (500) in 2.57 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id was:
>   38834edf-c9f3-46bb-a1f7-b2839c692bcf-2012-06-12 22:25:14Z dateTime:
>   Wed Jun 13 2012 10:25:17 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>   durationSeconds: 2.57 url: Websites/UpdateConfig status: 500
>   textStatus: error clientMsRequestId:
>   38834edf-c9f3-46bb-a1f7-b2839c692bcf-2012-06-12 22:25:14Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com response: {"message":"Try again. Contact
>   support if the problem persists.","ErrorMessage":"Try again. Contact
>   support if the problem
>   persists.","httpStatusCode":"InternalServerError","operationTrackingId":"","stackTrace":null}
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to: Websites/GetConfig. completed with
>   status: success (200) in 1.021 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id was:
>   a0cdcced-13d0-44e2-866d-e0b061b9461b-2012-06-12 22:24:43Z dateTime:
>   Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:44 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>   durationSeconds: 1.021 url: Websites/GetConfig status: 200 textStatus:
>   success clientMsRequestId:
>   a0cdcced-13d0-44e2-866d-e0b061b9461b-2012-06-12 22:24:43Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/Service/OperationTracking?subscriptionId=3aabe358-d178-4790-a97b-ffba902b2851.
>   completed with status: success (200) in 1.887 seconds.
>   x-ms-client-request-id was:
>   a7689fe9-b9f9-4d6c-8926-734ec9a0b515-2012-06-12 22:24:40Z dateTime:
>   Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:42 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>   durationSeconds: 1.887 url:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/Service/OperationTracking?subscriptionId=3aabe358-d178-4790-a97b-ffba902b2851
>   status: 200 textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   a7689fe9-b9f9-4d6c-8926-734ec9a0b515-2012-06-12 22:24:40Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to: /Service/GetUserSettings. completed
>   with status: success (200) in 0.941 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id
>   was: 805e554d-1e2e-4214-afd5-be87c0f255d1-2012-06-12 22:24:40Z
>   dateTime: Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:40 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard
>   Time) durationSeconds: 0.941 url: /Service/GetUserSettings status: 200
>   textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   805e554d-1e2e-4214-afd5-be87c0f255d1-2012-06-12 22:24:40Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/ClusterSuffix. completed
>   with status: success (200) in 0.483 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id
>   was: 85157ceb-c538-40ca-8c1e-5cc07c57240f-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z
>   dateTime: Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:40 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard
>   Time) durationSeconds: 0.483 url:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/ClusterSuffix status: 200
>   textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   85157ceb-c538-40ca-8c1e-5cc07c57240f-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/GetClientIp. completed with
>   status: success (200) in 0.309 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id was:
>   2eb194b6-66ca-49e2-9016-e0f89164314c-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z dateTime:
>   Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:40 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>   durationSeconds: 0.309 url:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/GetClientIp status: 200
>   textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   2eb194b6-66ca-49e2-9016-e0f89164314c-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/DefaultServerLocation.
>   completed with status: success (200) in 0.309 seconds.
>   x-ms-client-request-id was:
>   1bc165ef-2081-48f2-baed-16c6edf8ea67-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z dateTime:
>   Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:40 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
>   durationSeconds: 0.309 url:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/DefaultServerLocation
>   status: 200 textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   1bc165ef-2081-48f2-baed-16c6edf8ea67-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com
>
> message: Complete: Ajax call to:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/ServerLocations. completed
>   with status: success (200) in 0.309 seconds. x-ms-client-request-id
>   was: e1fba7df-6a12-47f8-9434-bf17ca7d93f4-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z
>   dateTime: Wed Jun 13 2012 10:24:40 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard
>   Time) durationSeconds: 0.309 url:
>   Extensions/ApplicationsExtension/SqlAzure/ServerLocations status: 200
>   textStatus: success clientMsRequestId:
>   e1fba7df-6a12-47f8-9434-bf17ca7d93f4-2012-06-12 22:24:39Z sessionId:
>   09c72263-6ce7-422b-84d7-4c21acded759 referrer:
>   https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/reemdairy/configure
>   host: manage.windowsazure.com

Answer (score 2):

Its good that you have Windows Azure Website (Reserve) because only Reserve websites can have CNAME or A record point to your_site.azurewebsites.net.

May I ask what are you setting, CNAME or A Record?

Here is the step by step direction on setting either CNAME (which is suggested for websites and webroles) so please follow and suggest at what step you have an issue:

[Configuring a Custom Domain Name in Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

Comment: It seems that my DNS provider does not allow me to add CNAMEs, only URL redirection.  Might need a new DNS provider.

Comment: URL Redirection is not good as it will display the redirected URL name (*.azurewesites.net) in the URL window as well as the hostheader. When you will use CNAME or A Record, your hostheader will be exactly as your domain name in  all the requests.

Comment: I tried changing to another DNS provider that allowed me to add a www CNAME as per the instructions, I then added the URL to my website config through the Azure portal but it still didn't work!

Comment: Would you please write above about your settings and also suggest when you use your domainname.com what result you see?

Comment: I read this everywhere "because only Reserve websites" even on the Microsoft sites. But what's preventing me from creating a CNAME record to a non-reserved instance of an Azure website on azurewebsites.net? I don't see any technical limitations. Is MS preventing this, if so, is there some article/documentation on it?

Comment: Yes, the CNAME configuration for any Azure Websites is set in property page at portal. If your website is not "Reserved", the CNAME setup property will not populate and there is nothing you could do to set CNAME for your shared website.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully done this with the exact same setup (Umbraco, running on Azure with a domains4less.co.nz domain). DNS setup with Domains4less can be obtuse - but here's how to setup a CNAME to your app:

From 'Manage Domains', hit 'Setup' on the domain you want. Next page, 'Advanced Control Panel' and login. Expand 'Services', open 'Domain Templates' and click 'Add a domain template'

Give your template a name (e.g 'yourdomain.co.nz'), and scroll down to the CNAME Records section. Click 'Add a CNAME record', Prefix field: `www`, Destination Address: `YOURAPPNAME.azurewebsites.net.`. Save.

Open 'Domains' in the left-side menu and click '[edit]' on the domain you want to setup, open the 'Advanced Mode' tab and choose your template from the Template drop-down list. Save, done.

Phew.